# Search a text file with list of ad servers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a program that blocks ads. I have found a list of ad servers from [this](https://pgl.yoyo.org/as/serverlist.php?hostformat=nohtml&showintro=1&startdate%5Bday%5D=&startdate%5Bmonth%5D=&startdate%5Byear%5D=) page. My question: is it possible to search for these ad servers from that page in a website using javascript? and please note that I would like code for an extension

Comment: can you be more precise on how you want to block those ads? if you plan to disable links, images or iframes manually by removing tags, i guess a basic search and replace in the page html will do..

Comment: @Kaddath yes I want to disable links and images. If you could provide an answer on that that would be really good

Comment: Added a working example for you in my answer. If you want to filter out more elements, you can add more for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
var sites = ['site1', 'site2', '...'],
    sites_len = sites.length;
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0, len = els.length; i < len; i++) {
    var attr = "";
    switch (els[i].tagName.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'iframe':
        case 'script':
        case 'img':
            attr = 'src';
            break;
        case 'link':
        case 'a':
            attr = 'href';
            break
        default:
            continue;
    }
    var attr_val = els[i].getAttribute(attr);
    for (var j = 0; j < sites_len; j++)
        if (sites[j].indexOf(attr_val) > -1)
            els[i].parentNode.reamoveChild(els[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, a web page cannot access the content of another webpage in JavaScript. This is known as [cross-origin HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). The website can allow different websites to access its content using the HTTP header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, but your page, in particular, is not doing that.

If you go ahead and try you will get the error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://pgl.yoyo.org/as/serverlist.php?hostformat=nohtml&showintro=1&startdate%5Bday%5D=&startdate%5Bmonth%5D=&startdate%5Byear%5D=. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

To work around this limitation you could develop a browser extension instead or use a proxy like [crossorigin.me](https://crossorigin.me/).

This is a working example:

```js
function loadAdServers(callback) {
  const url = 'https://crossorigin.me/https://pgl.yoyo.org/as/serverlist.php?hostformat=nohtml&showintro=1&startdate%5Bday%5D=&startdate%5Bmonth%5D=&startdate%5Byear%5D=';

  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url);
  request.addEventListener('load', function () {
    callback(request.response.split('\n').filter(x => x));
  });
  request.send();
}

function removeElement(element) {
  if (element.parentElement) {
    element.parentElement.removeChild(element);
  }
}

function removeAdElements(adServers) {
  for (const img of document.querySelectorAll('img')) {
    for (const adServer of adServers) {
      if (img.src.indexOf(adServer) >= 0) {
        removeElement(img);
      }
    }
  }
  for (const a of document.querySelectorAll('a')) {
    for (const adServer of adServers) {
      if (a.href.indexOf(adServer) >= 0) {
        removeElement(a);
      }
    }
  }
}

loadAdServers(removeAdElements);
```

```html
  <img src="http://101order.com/company.logo">
  <a href="http://101order.com/">Link</a>
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>
```

It takes some time to load the list and filter the elements.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I tried to put this into an extension and it didn't work. Do you have any idea how to utilise this in an extension?

Comment: I am sorry, but I have never done an extension before. I think you won't need to use `https://crossorigin.me`, but I don't know how to access the DOM from the extension.